# Get a error in OAuth: SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify

Tags: oauth, certificate, verify

Last week the counter party changed there ssl certificate (before that everything was working fine). Now i get a error when i try to get a token.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$key = 'xxx';
$secret = 'xxx';
$url = 'https://app.xx.com';

try {
    $oauth = new OAuth($key, $secret);
    $oauth->enableDebug();
    $access_token_info = $oauth->getAccessToken($url. '/oauth/request_token');
    if(!empty($access_token_info)) {
        print_r($access_token_info);
    } else {
        print "Failed fetching access token, response was: " . $oauth->getLastResponse();
    }
} catch(OAuthException $E) {
    echo "Response: ". $E->lastResponse . "\n";
}
```

**Warning**: OAuth::getAccessToken(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

**Warning**: OAuth::getAccessToken(): Failed to enable crypto

I tried the coded on a second server and there it works fine so it looks like the problem is on my side.

What can be the problem and how can i fix this?

Comment: @Imo: Thanks for the respons.

After a lot of testing i finely found the problem. The counter party forgot to install the correct intermediate certificate.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely you lack a CA certificate of a new Authority of their new certificate.
It depends on your distribution, but often the trusted CAs are placed in `/etc/ssl/certs/`. Check if this directory includes the same certs as your second server.